# Stellar vertical offset - background scrolls down creating a whitespace

Tags: stellar.js

I have searched and researched stackoverflow but couldn't find any good answer that might help me.

I am using stellar.js to create parallax backgrounds, but sometimes as I scroll the page, the background goes down, creating a white space (instead of creating the parallax effect).

Here is a preview of the image with explanation:

http://s30.postimg.org/owb86e3bk/stellar.jpg

Any ideas would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Same problem here...

Answer (score 0):

```
$.stellar({
    horizontalScrolling:false
});
```

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation would help current and future readers to understand it even better.